# Parent <div> not wrapping child element with float attribute

Tags: css, html

Please look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/M68xL/) and explain to me why the green `<div>` does not wrap itself around the orange `<div>`.

```
<div id='green'>
  <div id="orange"></div>
</div>

#green{
    border: 20px solid #3D3;
}

#orange{
    width :100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 10px solid orange;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try adding `float:left` and `display:block` to the outer div

see updated example - http://jsfiddle.net/jordanlewis/gDtSZ/1/

Comment: You probably already know, but anything floated automatically becomes block level :)

Comment: Wow, I have been stuck on the same problem for a couple hours now. Thanks!

Comment: If you have some children floated to the left as well as right then use `width: 100%` along with `float: left` to the parent div

Comment: But what if I want to center the parent div?

Answer (score 30):

Elements do not expand to contain floated children by default.

There are a number of workarounds, such as floating the parent, using a *clearfix* or adding `overflow: hidden` to the parent.

Personally, I try and use the latter.

[Here is your jsFiddle working](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/M68xL/1/).

Comment: I found `overflow: hidden` was the most efficient, least side-effect-prone fix for my own code.

Comment: nice approach if you do not have anything in this parent that displays as a tooltip because it will get cut if it goes out of the parent region.

Comment: Great solution, but why does it work? 

I just double checked https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow for my understanding of this command and it seems that this should hide content if it doesn't fit. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

and if you don't want to float your outer div to left you can set it to

`display:table`

this will make the outer div wrap around the inner one.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div id='green'>
  <div id="orange"></div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Like your code sample, would love even more some text explaining what "clear:both" does in this scenario, and why it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The green box is not a floated element.

You need to either clear your float after the nested div or float both.

Comment: Love your explanation, would love even more the sample code to show exactly what this solution looks like in code.

Answer (score 1):

you could just add display:inline-block to the orange box.

Comment: how is "inline-block" different than "block" and why does this setting work?

Comment: Block elements do not allow other element to be displayed on the same line as it, on the other hand, Inline-block permits this but also posses some Block element properties.